# What do you recommend to find a particular constraint in a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints, transform, uiviewanimation

I wonder if you add a constraint to a view and didn't keep the constraint pointer, how can you find that particular constraint in a view later?

I tried this for an view animation. I thought I could iterate through all the constraints in the view and find the particular one in the list. 
But, it was not. There are so many constraints.

I got the impression that finding one is almost impossible unless I had the pointer for that constraint so that I can have them matched.

So, I'd like to know if such is the best way to find a constraint.

And, Here's another question.
Previously I accessed the transform value directly to change the frame rect for animation. But, 'with' constraints I cannot access the frame rect directly, rather I have it changed by giving appropriate constraints. Is there any way to use transform value with constraints?

Comment: You can set the identifier for the constraint to identify it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set an identifier to a constraint

```
myConstraint.identifier = "<MyIdentifierText>";
```

Get constraint using identifier:

```
NSArray *constraints = [myView constraints];

for (int index = 0; index < [constraints count]; index ++)
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = constraints[index];
    if ( [constraint.identifier isEqualToString:@"<MyIdentifierText>"] ) {

        // save the reference to constraint
        // or do the necessary operations
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Hope this helps.